# How to place a users role after username in Forums

Tags: views, nodes

On my site, i have the Forums module enabled.

Please is it possible to put a users role in parenthesis next to the users username in the Forums?

For example "Brian (Student)" and David (Teacher)".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the display in views.

You can add a  "User: Roles" Field. Mark it as excluded.

Then

Under "user: name" field. select "Rewrite the output of this field" and include the [rid-role] token in the username.

Be sure to add the "role field" before "user field" otherwise the token will not be available.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqZhn.png)